# Distribution function for two independent exponential distribution

Tags: probability

"Lifetime of all computers are independent exponential variables. 60% of the computers are laptops with λ=1 and the remaining are desktops with λ=8.

If a computer is selected randomly, find the distribution function of itd lifetime."

I'm not quite sure what to do, but my intuition is adding both the cdfs.

Answer (score 0):

If you add two CDF's you will not get a CDF, because the resulting function will have a range between $0$ and $2$, not $0$ and $1$.

Use the law of total probability. Let $L$ be the lifetime of the computer:
$$P(L \leq x) = P(L \leq x \mid \text{ laptop})P(\text{laptop})+P(L \leq x \mid \text{ desktop})P(\text{desktop}).$$

Comment: Ahh i see.. but isn't it P(L≤x)=P(laptop≤x | laptop)P(laptop) + P(desktop≤x | desktop)P(desktop)?

Comment: How can a laptop be $\leq x$? I think what you mean to say is that $P(L \leq x \mid \text{ laptop})$ is the probability that a laptop's lifetime (i.e., an exponential RV with $\lambda = 1$) is $\leq x$, and similarly $P(L \leq x \mid \text{ desktop})$ is the probability that a desktop's lifetime (i.e., an exponential RV with $\lambda = 8$) is $\leq x$.

Comment: wait scrap that.. how do i solve for (≤) then?

Comment: Use the law of total probability as I said in my answer. I explained in my comment what the conditional probabilities are. What part of that needs clarification?